# Specify an argument should implement more than one trait

Tags: groovy

To illustrate my question, better as an example: Lets say I want to host a triathlon, whereby `triathletes` have to `Swim, Run, Cycle`, so I have 3 traits:

```
trait Swimmer {
    abstract void swim()
}

trait Runner {
    abstract void run()
}

trait Cyclist {
    abstract void cycle()
}
```

All these traits together make up a `Triathlete`:

```
trait Triathlete extends Swimmer, Runner, Cyclist {
}
```

Which can then do a triathlon:

```
def triathlon(Triathlete triathlete) {
    triathlete.run()
    triathlete.cycle()
    triathlete.swim()
}
```

Currently I am defining a DSL in groovy, and in this use case, it doesn't really make sense to define this intermediate trait `Triathlete`. So is there a way to declare `triathlon`, using `Swimmer & Runner & Cyclist`?

I don't know if there is anything in the language itself to do this, I imagine there is a way to do this with `AstBuilder` or the likes but I am not there yet with my level of groovy to implement something like this, but I am looking for something like this

```
void triathlon(Swimmer & Runner & Cyclist triathlete) {
    triathlete.run()
    triathlete.cycle()
    triathlete.swim()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured this out, just putting this for others to use, you can use generics here, pure Java no Groovy needed:

```
static <T extends Swimmer & Runner & Cyclist> void triathlon(T triathlete) {
    triathlete.run()
    triathlete.cycle()
    triathlete.swim()
}
```